# Creating custom jQuery class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a photo gallery for my website. I want a grid of the photos displayed when the page loads. Then when the user hovers over each photo, the photo enlarges a little.

I created the javascript for the hovering, but I do not know how to properly package this into a class.

Basically, I want to just create a list like this

```
<ul>
 <li><img src="img1.jpg" /></li>
 <li><img src="img2.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

And then it automatically creates each image with my hovering mechanism already in place.
Here is my code thus far.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<style text="text/css">
.hoverImage {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    left: 500px;
    top: 200px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var originalWidth;
var originalHeight;

function onHover() {
    originalWidth = $(this).width();
    originalHeight = $(this).height();

    $(this).stop(false, true).animate({
            left: $(this).offset().left-(Math.floor(originalWidth/4)),
            top: $(this).offset().top-(Math.floor(originalHeight/4)),
            width: 300,
    },200);
}

function offHover() {
    $(this).stop(false, true).animate({
            left: $(this).offset().left+(Math.floor(originalWidth/4)),
            top: $(this).offset().top+(Math.floor(originalHeight/4)),
            width: 200,
    },200);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").hover(onHover, offHover);
});

</script>
<img class="hoverImage" src="Test.jpg"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: by class do you mean a jQuery plugin? Can you be a bit more clear?

Comment: I am not sure how to communicate what I am wanting. It's the best word I could think of :/ I am looking for something similar to how lightbox is done http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#how

Comment: I think you want to extend jquery so that you can get this type of syntax, $('ul').relyntsHoverPlugin(); right?

Comment: Use Firebug and check what classes get added to the element. Then you can define that class (for example `.ui-widget.header { /* your style */}` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extend the jQuery DOM object with your own method this should be the way to do it

```
$.fn.extend({
    relyntsHoverPlugin : function() {}
});
```

this will allow for syntax like

```
$('ul').relyntsHoverPlugin();
```

Not to be confused with extending the jQuery object with a new function, ie. **$**.relyntsMethod();

Hope this helps and that I wasn't totally off base!

Comment: I believe this is what I am looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wrap your functionality into something reuable, considering writing a jQuery extension. It's not hard.

Here's the guide: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Answer (score 0):

You can use templates to create images in grid/div/table... and add onHover() and offHover() for images. Hope it helps you.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var data = [
    { name: "Astor", product: "astor", stocklevel: "10"},
    { name: "Daffodil", product: "daffodil", stocklevel: "12"},
    { name: "Rose", product: "rose", stocklevel: "2"},
    { name: "Peony", product: "peony", stocklevel: "0"},
    ];
    $('#flowerTmpl').tmpl(data).appendTo('#row1');
    });
    </script>

    <script id="flowerTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <div class="dcell">
    <img src="${product}.png"/>
    <label for="${product}">${name}:</label>
    </div>
    </script>
```