# Creating function with action in jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, eval

I want to create function:

```
$('#element').myFunct(function(){
    alert('1');
});
```

Trying something like this:

```
$.fn.outClick = function(fn){
    eval(fn);

    //OR

    $.globalEval(fn);
}
```

Can use this solution:

```
$.fn.outClick = function(fn){
    $.globalEval('myFn='+fn);
    myFn();
}
```

But this is not good solution.

Is there any right method?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594706/creating-custom-jquery-class/10594814#10594814

Comment: Why do you need to use `globalEval`?

Comment: @limelights this answer give me that I already have, need to make `$('ul').relyntsHoverPlugin(function{alert('1')});` works.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I don't need, there is just some methods that I tried.